# Proving that $\exists f \in X^*$ : $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ and $\|f\| = \|x\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem, hahn-banach-theorem

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a normed space. Prove that for all $x \in X$ there exists $f \in X^*$, such that $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ and $ \|f\| = \|x \|$.

**Thoughts :**

I apologise for not providing a proper attempt but this is one of the first such exercises I'm handling, so I seem at loss.

Initially, I thought about the Riesz Representation Theorem, which could yield the result straightforward, but the space we are working over must be a Hilbert Space, which we do not know in the given exercise.

The second possible solution could (and probably should) be based on the Hahn-Banach Theorem (or one of its results/applications) but I cannot see a way out.

**Any hints or elaborations will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=0$, we are done. Now let $x \in X$ and $x \ne 0$. A consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem is the existence of some $g \in X^*$ with

$g(x)=||x||$ and $||g||=1.$

Now it is easy to see that $f:=||x||g$ has the desired properties.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Fix an $x\in X$. If $x=0$ then the answer is rather easy, so we can assume $x\neq 0$.

Next, define a suitable functional on the linear hull of $x$, which is the linear subspace $V:=\{ \alpha \cdot x | \alpha \in \mathbb R\}$.
Then extend this functional onto the whole space $X$ using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Let's say $f : \langle x : x \in X \rangle \to \mathbb R$ with $f(y) = \langle y,x \rangle$. Then we can see that $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ and $\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|} = \|x\| \implies \|f\| = \|x\|$. But $ \langle x : x \in X \rangle \subseteq X $ and one can see that the $f$ defined is a bounded linear functional, thus it can be extended to $X$ which implies that $\exists f \in X^*$ such that $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ and $\|f\| = \|x\|$. Does that make sense or do I have any errors ?

Comment: I just saw your edit. I would appreciate an input regarding my attempted approach and/or an input regarding an approach you would recommend.

Comment: No, your approach does not work since $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is not defined on $X$. $X$ is only a normed vector space in your question.
Also the notation $<x : x\in X>$ is not a standard notation. if it is a set it would use $\{\}$ instead of $<>$.
Note that $X=\{x:x\in X\}$, so your space is not a proper subspace of $X$.

Comment: $\langle \rangle$ denotes the linear hull. If my approach is not correct, would you mind elaborating as such, in order to properly understand ? I guess another proper functional will be $f : \{\lambda \cdot x | x \in X, \; \lambda \in \mathbb R\} \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\|x\|^2$ ?

Comment: You should work with a fixed $x$ and not use it as a variable for the definition of functions or sets. Note that your suggestion for $f$ is not linear.

With the linear hull notation, the space should be $V=\langle x \rangle$, which has dimension $1$.

Comment: I get why we consider the linear hull of $x$ since it's a proper subspace of $X$ and helps us fit the Hahn-Banach theorem. I can't seem to find the properly defined bounded linear functional $f$ though, what would that be ?